# Why is the gradient on top not fading to the background color?

Tags: feature-request

Every time I visit Pro Webmasters, the look of the header pains me.

[image]

Why is the header background not fading *into* the background color? Like so:

[image]

Well, I like it. Maybe you'll like it too. The *new* background can be grabbed from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yeh5.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Arguably because the division produces a "shelf" for the tabs to sit on rather than just floating in the air with no clear relation to anything; the line also creates an overall container for the header content versus question list/sidebar below. In fact, the point at which you decided to fade the gradient out actually tends to end up associating the tabs more with the list below than indicate they're part of the header(they're somewhat related, but still a separate process/path from the active/featured/etc links.). That effect will be even worse on single-question screens where they're completely unrelated to the content below.

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) basically does what you're describing, though more starkly; compare how noisy it looks up top.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense :)